# Get staus if python tests all passed

Tags: python, ruby, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a Ruby script to execute all Python tests in a directory.
Here is the main part of the script:

```
system("python #{solution}/tests.py")
```

Is there a way to somehow understand if the tests have passed and to show output only for the ones that failed (or whatever else)? I just want to be able to tell for each test if it passed or not. (If not possible with Ruby, I'm open for solutions with Python, too)

The tests all look like this one:

```
import unittest
from solution import my_function

class MyFunctionTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_function(self):
        self.assertEqual(42, my_function(42))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Thanks very much in advance! :)

Comment: Are you just trying to run all of the tests in a directory to see if they pass or fail?

Comment: Mmm yes, that would be fine, too, but the main goal is to print output only for the failing ones. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the output for failing tests with `nosetests`, which runs them all and condenses the passing tests:

```
$ nosetests
.............
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.015s

OK
```

Adding a failing test:

```
$ nosetests
F.............
======================================================================
FAIL: test_failed (x32.tests.failing_test.FailingTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leigh/Projects/x32/x32/tests/failing_test.py", line 5, in test_failed
    self.assertEqual(1, 2)
AssertionError: 1 != 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 14 tests in 0.013s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

There's a guide for `nose` here, as well: https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Alternatively you can go to the parent directory and run something like `python -m pytest .` to execute the tests, however this will tell you which ones pass as well.